# Перегрузка метода __init__() в python

Tags: python

Можно ли как нибудь перегрузить метод `__init__()` что бы создавать объект не так: название_объекта = название_класса(переменные), а как нибудь по другому?

Comment: Как-нибудь это как?

Comment: Как у add() это +, то есть вместо метода просто писать какой нибудь символ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструкторы в Python не перегружаются как конструкторы в С++.

Можно использовать  classmethod

> Методы класса принимают класс в качестве параметра, который принято
>   обозначать как cls. Он указывает на класс Foo, а не на объект
>   этого класса. При декларации методов этого вида используется декоратор
>   classmethod.
>
> Методы класса привязаны к самому классу, а не его экземпляру. Они
>   могут менять состояние класса, что отразится на всех объектах этого
>   класса, но не могут менять конкретный объект.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    @classmethod
    def fromfilename(cls, filename):
        data = open(filename).readlines()
        return cls(data)

    @classmethod
    def fromdict(cls, datadict):
         return cls(datadict.items())

p1=Foo([1, 2, 3])
p2=Foo.fromfilename("foo.bar")
p3=Foo.fromdict({"spam": "ham"})
```

[Более подробно](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classmethod-in-python/) о применении classmethod